# Access properties file in external jar

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Need to access the property file (db.properties) in a jar(database.jar) from the spring batch application jar(app.jar)..

I tried to get the property values in the spring batch

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("database.properties");
prop.load(in); // in value is null
```

added database.jar in classpath and ran the app.jar in the shell command..

How should I proceed?

Comment: Although there are certainly easier ways to read a properties in Spring, have you tried using `InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("/database.properties").getInputStream()`?

Comment: Yes.. Tried with these option also.. The way of fetching the value is correct or did i missed any??

Comment: And it didn't work? Where have you placed the file `database.properties`?

Comment: Placed in database.jar.. Both the jar are placed in same folder and shell command is trigerred

Comment: Are you sure that database.jar is acutally in the classpath? Can you access class from this jar when you launch your application?